# macOS: How to eject a remote disk?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, finder, macos

I've a problem with my MacBook Pro 2017 running macOS 10.12.6 Sierra: I cannot eject a remote disk that was mounted. No app is using the disk.

How can I eject the remote disk properly?

Comment: Have you tried `diskutil unmountDisk force /Volumes/DISK_NAME`?

Comment: How do you try to eject it? What errors do you get? How did you verify that no application/process is using the disk?

Comment: @bret7600 inside /Volumes I can find only Macintosh HD

Comment: @patrix I selected the unit and then I pressed cmd+E. No error appeared. I just typed top on terminal and guessed what app can use the disk

Comment: What is wrong with the question?

Comment: The question is a bit low on details, making it difficult to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer in the apple support, namely write the following

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkBrowser EnableODiskBrowsing -bool false
```

and then

```
killall Finder
```

To enable again just write true in place of false.